# Calling slide out cart from sticky add to cart bar button

Tags: shopify

- I have a sticky add-to-cart button based on `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loRbZ2hOzhY`.
- I changed the code of the Dawn 11.0 theme based on the above video and the sticky `add-to-cart` bar is working.

The problem is, when I click the `"Add to Cart"` button of the sticky add to cart bar, the slide-out drawer cart does not appear. But when I click the regular `"Add to cart"` button on the product page, the slide-out drawer cart appears with animation as it should.

I have done the following but it is not working. If someone can help, it would be great...

1. I have added an asset and called it CartDrawerPull.js
2. For the above script, I added the script reference in the theme. liquid
3. Wrote the following code for capturing `/cart/add` an action for all forms and added an event listener and allowed it to handle default and added animate and active class.

````
document.querySelectorAll('form[action="/cart/add"]').forEach((form) => {
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
// e.preventDefault(); 
document.querySelector('.cart-drawer').classList.add ('animate','active');
});
}) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I just installed a fresh install of dawn 11.0.0.

I am assuming that you still have the asset `cart-notification.js` still configured in the Dawn theme.

But the following code works for me.

The `cart.renderContents(response);` is the method that renders the cart drawer. But you need the `getSectionsToRender` to render correctly.

```js
const cart = document.querySelector("cart-notification");

let addToCartForms = document.querySelectorAll('form[action$="/cart/add"]');

addToCartForms.forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(e.target);

    const config = {};
    if (cart) {
      formData.append(
        "sections",
        cart.getSectionsToRender().map((section) => section.id)
      );
      formData.append("sections_url", window.location.pathname);
      cart.setActiveElement(document.activeElement);
    }
    config.body = formData;

    fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + "cart/add.js", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        cart.renderContents(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
  var variantBut = document.querySelector('.sticky-bar-form .variant-button');  
  // var variantBut = document.querySelector('.variant-button');  
  
 variantBut.addEventListener('click', function() 
 { **\\ yourcode \\**}); `     On debug, fetch() works ok. Getting response with product detail . However, 'cart' remains 'null' at cart.renderContents(). Do I need to put the code I mentioned in this comment in cart-notification.js, separate asset? BTW cart notification type config is drawer in theme customisation. Plesae help.

Comment: If I turn the Cart Notification type to "Popup notification", `Cart` object becomes valid but then I am getting error that `Cart.getSectionToRender()` . I want a slideout drawer from left

Answer (score 1):

Cheers! I could make it work with lot of trial on debugging but not without code from @bryan89tran to whom I a owe big thank. I modified @bryan89tran code after debugging and code I am using is as below now :

Instruct for anyone who wants to replicate

1. Add an asset. Let's call is `CartDrawerPull.js`
2. Put below code in `CartDrawerPull.js`
3. Ensure `theme.liquid` has following line
   `<script src="{{ 'CartDrawerPull.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>`
4. Save `CartDrawerPull.js` and `theme.liquid`
5. Now when `Add to Cart` button is clicked on `sticky add to cart bar`, slide out drawer will appear.

I am happy for me as I am learning Shopify customisation and this is my third hit.

Below is code for `CartDrawerPull.js` :

````
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
  var variantBut = document.querySelector('.sticky-bar-form .variant-button');  
    
 variantBut.addEventListener('click', function() 
 {
        var cart = document.querySelector(".drawer");
   

        let addToCartForms = document.querySelectorAll('form[action$="/cart/add"]');

      addToCartForms.forEach((form) => 
      {
        form.addEventListener("submit",async (e) => 
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          let formData = new FormData(e.target);

          const config = {};
          if (cart) 
          {
            formData.append("sections", cart.getSectionsToRender().map((section) => section.id) );
            formData.append("sections_url", window.location.pathname);
            cart.setActiveElement(document.activeElement); 
          }

          config.body = formData;

          fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + "cart/add.js", {method: "POST", body: formData,})
            .then((response) => {return response.json();})
            .then((response) => { console.log(response); cart.renderContents(response);})
            .catch((error) => {console.error("Error:", error); });
        });
      });
    });
    });```
````

Comment: Hey! Sorry just came back to this! Wonderful!! Awesome work! We did it!!

Comment: @bryan89tran...but now i am facing a different issue... When 1st product is added , cart appears but it appears blank ! only when second product is added both are getting visible. Not able to sort that out....can you help with above code modification?

Comment: Hey just saw this. hmmmm I wonder if `renderContents` isn't doing what we think its doing. It is possible that it's refetching the cart. And it's doing it too quickly? This sucks, but maybe.... put a small setTimeout to see if that theory is true.